# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'result'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out why I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'result'
```

This happens whenever I try to include the following javascript code:

```
$("#searchall").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
if (data){
    $('#searchall_num').val(data[1]); 
        rollnum=$('#searchall_num').val();
        var calcyear;
        $.ajax({ 
            url: sURL + "utility/ajaxLatestTaxCalcYear",
            type: "POST",
            data: {rn: rollnum},
            success: function(LatestTaxCalcYear){ 
            //. . . . etc.
```

The error happens whether this javascript code is inside the `$(document).ready(function () {` or outside.  Any ideas what is triggering this error?

EDIT:

I should have included this originally.  This js code is also on the page:

```
$("#searchall").autocomplete(sURL + "home/ajaxSelectAddress/");
```

This is the trigger for an autocomplete.  The `result` referred to in the earlier code is supposed to be triggered when an item is selected from the autocomplete.

There have been some good suggestions so far, which I am currently investigating.  Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you defined a `result` method somewhere? As is the error would occur unless you did something like this: `$.fn.result= function(){}`. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [jQueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) documentation. You should be using the `select` event for when an item is selected.

```
$("#searchall").autocomplete({
    source: sURL + "home/ajaxSelectAddress/",
    select: function(e,ui) {
        //whatever you want here
    }
});
```